# Conformal mappings to polygons: why is my integral conformal?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I'm learning about conformal mappings into polygons in a class,(undergrad complex analysis) and am having trouble understanding one of the examples given in my book. (Stein & Shakarchi) Here it is:

For $z\in\mathbb{H}$(the open upper half plane), define 
\begin{align*}
f(z) := \int_{0}^{z}\frac{1}{(1-\zeta^{2})^{1/2}}d\zeta
\end{align*}
The example goes on to talk about the boundary behavior of this function, which I'm o.k. with. It also says that $f$ is the inverse of $\sin(z)$, and thus is conformal from $\mathbb{H}$ to a "half-strip" described in the book. Is there another way we can see that $f$ is conformal?

Comment: I've found out why $f$ is holom. - it's the same proof as the proof that any holomorphic function in a simply connected domain has a primitive.(see Stein & Shkarchi theorem 5.2, chapter 3)

Answer (score 1):

The connection between conformal mapping and complex variables is about as fundamental an idea in complex variables as there is.  This connection is the first example mentioned on the [Wikipedia page for conformal map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).

This basic observation is that a differentiable function behaves like it's linear approximation on a small scale.  In symbols, for $z$ close to $z_0$, we have
$$f(z) \approx f(z_0) + f'(z_0)(z-z_0)$$
with an error proportional to $|z-z_0|^2$.  Thus, for $z$ close to $z_0$, a function that is differentiable in a neighborhood of $z_0$ with $f'(z_0)\neq0$ looks approximately affine, that is it looks like a function of the form $g(z)=az+b$.  Now, multiplication by a complex number $a$ scales by $|a|$ and rotates by $\arg(a)$.  Adding a complex number $b$ simply shifts the whole picture.  These operations preserve angle measure so that an affine function does as well and a differentiable function with non-vanishing derivative does as well.